# Action "send mail" not available for new contact

Tags: activity, sendmail

Activity type id=8 (send mail) is shown for all contacts.
We made a new contact today, and "send mail" did not shown up in the activity drop down.

We don't have any idea where to look first, because the list of activity types is ok, and the new contact has the same subtype as all the others.

Comment: does the contact have a valid email id available on its record?

Comment: @jitendra-fuzion, when making the contact, the mail field was indeed forgotten. Stupid error. As soon as I saw it, I wanted to delete my post, but you did reply meanwhile. So I will keep it in respect for your very fast reply!

Answer (score 1):

The email field was forgotten...